# How to use npm with an old version of node in docker?

Tags: node.js, npm, dockerfile, npm-start

I'm trying to make a container that uses npm with node 14.10.0 but I can't get npm to use the correct version.
I already tried modifying the NODE_VERSION variable in the official node images and rebuilding them, and following this guide to build it from scratch https://www.kabisa.nl/tech/nvm-in-docker/ . In both cases npm install the latest node version and only uses that instead. I can temporarily get it to use the right version with nvm use but I can't use nvm in a CMD or a ENTRYPOINT block for some reason.

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.10.0
#shows the correct version
RUN nvm use $NODE_VERSION && npm show node version

#error can't find nvm
#RUN which nvm
#but nvm still exists as a command
RUN nvm -v

#can't find NVM 
#CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "nvm use 14.10.0 && npm show node version"]
#uses latest version instead of the correct one
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npm show node version"]
```

I can get it to install and build with the correct node version with nvm use, but since I can't use that inside the CMD npm start uses the wrong version and it breaks the app.
Updating the app isn't an option. How can I make npm start the app with the correct node version in the container?

Comment: Why do you need to use nvm inside a docker container if you can simply indicate the needed version in `from`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `node:14.10` image to build upon if nvm isn't required. This image has node 14.10 already installed which you can expand upon. To do that, change your code to the following:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:14.10
...REST_OF_THE_DOCKER_FILE
```

Comment: `node:latest` is, as I write this, `node:19.3.0-bullseye`.

Comment: mistakenly wrote node:latest in the code example, thank you for correcting me

Comment: I tried making a dockerfile with just ```FROM node:14.10 \ CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npm show node version"] ``` but it stil displays 19.3.0 instead of 14.10.0.

Comment: I also tried running it on a clean VM just in case but it seems to be a problem with the image.

Comment: do you have `node` in package.json as a dependency? the node package installs a binary of node.js in the node_modules/.bin/node , and if you run your application through some command like `npm start`, which executes `node index.js` it will look for the node or any other binary in the node_modules/.bin/ first.

Comment: I tried both with and without `"engines": { "node": "14.10.0" }`  but it doesn't seem to make a difference. npm still shows the latest node version and the app doesn't work as it should when inside the container.